# Black screen with scrambled dialog appears at startup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, uefi, lenovo

[image: boot screen]

Every time I start my laptop, the image shown appears on the screen.

If I press <kbd>enter</kbd> then the GRUB screen appears.

Everything else is working fine.

Can anyone tell me how to avoid seeing the screen?

I have Ubuntu 18.04 along with Windows 10 installed on this laptop.

Comment: have you tried going to advanced boot options and adding nomodeset to the end of your boot command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu)

Comment: I tried it but it is still showing that screen on startup

Comment: Surely this is nothing to do with graphics as it happens before even GRUB loads. If everything else it working fine, I wouldn't set `nomodeset` which might cause poor resolution. I have an unfounded suspicion that screen is something to do with Windows Boot Manager. Could you give details about your hardware? Others will know better what details are needed

Comment: Lenovo g-50 80 laptop with i3 processor,4 GB ram and 64 bit os. This problem has started since I have updated Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04.